# Delete lines with id comming from a sub-select (work with SQLite, fail with MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have two tables : Table "GAME", and table "PLAYER". A player reference a game by a game_id. A game can contains several players. My application is supposed to work with MySQL and SQLite, and I do not use Foreign Key on theses tables.

My application allow to delete a game, by removing a line in the GAME table. So, some players may have a reference (game_id) to a not-existing-anymore GAME, this is fine for me.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80baf2/5

Now I want to delete "orphans" players : Any occurrence in PLAYER with an invalid GAME_ID must be deleted. I want to do it in a single query if possible.

I found a working solution with SQLite :

```
delete 
from 
  player 
where 
  player_id in (
    select
    P.player_id
    from player P
    left join game G on G.game_id = P.game_id
    where G.game_id is null
  )
```

But the very same query in MySQL return an error :

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'player' for update in FROM clause
```

It seems it is impossible to delete record in a TABLE where the IN clause contains reference in the same TABLE.

How can I acheive this in a single query, compatible with both MySQL and SQLite ?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80baf2/5

Answer (score 1):

Change your `delete` Query as below:

```
delete 
from 
  player 
where 
  player_id in (
    select * from ( 
        select
            P.player_id
            from player P
            left join game G on G.game_id = P.game_id
            where G.game_id is null
        ) as t
  )
```

The Reason is you cann't process a Table which is Locked for Deletion. Using the above Trick Mysql creates a Temporary Table and Delete Command is allowed to processed.

Answer (score 1):

Two options possible.

Use a extra subquery.

**Query**

```
delete 
from 
  player 
where 
  player_id in (
    select 
     player_alias.player_id
    from (
      select
      P.player_id
      from player P
      left join game G on G.game_id = P.game_id
      where G.game_id is null
    ) AS player_alias
  )
```

see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/534dad/1)

Or do a *"multiple"* table delete with a JOIN, which i would choose for to do instead as the query is much better to optimize with the right indexes..

**Query**

```
DELETE 
 player.*
FROM (
  select
   P.player_id
  from player P
  left join game G on G.game_id = P.game_id
  where G.game_id is null  
) AS player_delete
INNER JOIN 
 player 
ON
 player.player_id = player_delete.player_id
```

see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/940ecf5/1)

**Both deletes will keep**

```
| player_id |       name | game_id |
|-----------|------------|---------|
|       111 |  PlayerOne |      G1 |
|       222 | Player Two |      G1 |
```

**Edit**

The *"multiple"* table delete with a JOIN can be rewritten (much) more simple offcource.. 
Which as extra plus is also better for performance and memory wise also assuming MySQL can use the correct indexing for this query as `FROM (SELECT ..) AS <alias>` ([Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)) will also force MySQL to handle it as a [internal temporary table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html)

**Query**

```
  delete
    P.*
  from
    player P
  left join game G on G.game_id = P.game_id
  where G.game_id is null
```

see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6deaf0/1)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The latest query is not working with SQLite, so I use the select in select trick.

Comment: *"The latest query is not working with SQLite"* Oh yes @JayMore i mist *"How can I acheive this in a single query, compatible with both MySQL and SQLite ?"*